# Can't delete only const overload of method?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading

At least with unary `&` and unary `-` it appears GCC will only let you delete both the non-const and const version of an operator or none (it probably affects binary operators but I haven't checked). As described in the comments below, although I can successfully overload based on const, I cannot individually delete the const or non-const overload without running into a compile error. Is this behavior standard compliant? It seems counterintuitive.

Tested with GCC 5.4.0.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    // These both being defined at the same time is fine,
    // and whether or not x is const as expected will change
    // which overload you get.

    A* operator&() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
        return this;
    }

    const A* operator&() const {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
        return this;
    }



    // assuming both definitions above are commented out,
    // regardless of whether or not x is const
    // either one of these lines being present
    // will make the example not compile!

    // A* operator&() = delete;
    // const A* operator&() const = delete;



    // Finally if you have the const version defined and the non-const version deleted
    // or vice versa, it will compile as long as the one that you have defined
    // matches the constness of x.
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A x;
    std::cout << &x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `const` member function can be called on a non-`const` object. I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: @T.C. It can be, but the error occurs even when it is not called (when x is non-const and only the const version is deleted). It also happens in the opposite situation (const x with only the non-const version deleted). I tried to make this clear but it's admittedly tricky.

Comment: In the code above, if you comment `const A* operator&() const { ... }` and uncomment `const A* operator&() const = delete;` it compiles for a non-`const` `A` object. Similarly, you can get it to compile for a `const A` by commenting/uncommenting the other combination, so what is your question? Instead of all those comments in the code, maybe try posting all the versions that won't compile.

Comment: @Praetorian I tried to explain that would work in the third comment block. Try following the directions in the second comment block: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ebec6956aae7ace

Comment: As TC already said, `const` member functions can be called on non-`const` objects and the deleted function is the only available candidate in your example, so of course it doesn't compile. You can make the object `const` and it still won't compile for the same reason.

Comment: @Praetorian Say I had never defined or deleted any overloads at all. I would say the compiler generates 2 overloads by default for you, one that returns a const pointer and one that returns a regular one based on the const status of the object. If you delete one overload, the other should still exist, should it not?

Comment: OK, I understand your question now :) You're asking why the built-in `operator&` is not selected as a better match compared to your overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `operator&` does not participate in overload resolution ([[over.match.oper]/3.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.3)).

> For the `operator ,`, the **`unary operator &`**, or the `operator ->`, the built-in candidates set is empty.

Say you declare as deleted the overload below

```
const A* operator&() const = delete;
```

Regardless of whether you're trying to take the address of a `const` or non-`const` `A`, the declaration above is the only viable candidate, resulting in a compilation error.

If you comment it out, then the built-in `operator&` is found as per [[over.match.oper]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#9).

> If the operator is the `operator ,`, the **`unary operator &`**, or the `operator ->`, **and there are no viable functions, then the operator is assumed to be the built-in operator** and interpreted according to Clause [expr].

Now, if you declare as deleted the non-`const` overload only

```
A* operator&() = delete;
```

this cannot be called on a `const A` object, so it won't be a viable candidate and the built-in `operator&`  will be found.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f52693994f416ed)

---

When dealing with a class that overloads `operator&`, you can use [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to get the address of an instance.